# Select a range of files from directory structure /year/month/date.db

Tags: shell-script, files, directory, sort

I have databases stored in the directory structure

> year/month/date.db

an example would be

> db/2013/10/15.db

I need to be able to select a range of these with a script ("dbSelect 2013/09/01.db 2013/10/15.db" should output all .db files between those dates.

Any ideas as to how I could go about this?

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I would do. There may be a better/more elegant solution out there. This script should be run from the "db" directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

STARTDATE="2013/09/01"
ENDDATE="2013/10/15"

day=0

while [ "$DATE" != "$ENDDATE" ]; do
        DATE=`date --date="$STARTDATE + $day days" +%Y/%m/%d`
        if [ -f "$DATE.db" ]; then
                # This only echoes the file name, you might want to do something else here
                echo "$DATE.db"
        fi
        day=$(($day+1))
done
```

Edit: if you'd like it to accept arguments "./dbSelect.sh 2013/09/01 2013/10/15":

```
#!/bin/bash

STARTDATE="$1"
ENDDATE="$2"

day=0

while [ "$DATE" != "$ENDDATE" ]; do
        DATE=`date --date="$STARTDATE + $day days" +%Y/%m/%d`
        if [ -f "$DATE.db" ]; then
                # This only echoes the file name, you might want to do something else here
                echo "$DATE.db"
        fi
        day=$(($day+1))
done
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much for this! I am quite new to shell scripting so it is much appreciated.. sometimes you just get so lost!

Comment: These do have a bug: If there is something wrong with `$ENDDATE` (prior to start date, wrong format, etc.) then they will loop forever. You can use `date` to check for the conditions, however...

Comment: Yes, of course. This script has assumptions, and can be improved a lot more. That's for @user2894937 to improve ;-)